# React-native display Flatlist Component between Parent Flatlist Items

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

Working on a react-native application where I've to list Custom Items in a `FlatList`. This custom items contains two buttons. Clicking on each of it will get some data regarding to that clicked item and will display another `FlatList` with custom items in between that clicked item and it's next item.

Here in this link I've drawn that screen looks. Clicking on button B2 will get a list and display in between Parent `FlatList` item [See Screens Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11PxDz2_KQ6OxInZ2RMMEHz6zMjaiIf_u/view?usp=sharing)

I've tried with the `SectionList` where I'm displaying my first list data in `Headers` of `SectionList` with `Custom Component` with two buttons. Clicking on any, will get another list of items and assigned those data to clicked `section` header data. Those data will be displayed as child items to selected `Header` section. But it didn't workout as expected so looking for some alternate way with `FlatList`.

Answer (score 0):

Your main component will be like below:

```
export default class MainClass from React.Component{
     render(){
        <FlatList
             data={items}
             renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem/>}
        />
     }    
}
```

Your custom list item component will be like below:

```
export default class ListItem from React.Component{

     render(){
        <View>
          <View>
          //your card view which will contain B1 and B2 button
          </View>

         //below views will render conditionally
         <FlatList/> //if B2 button clicked then show fetched list
         <CalendarWidget/> //if B1 button clicked then show calendar data 
        </View>
     }  

}
```

Try to build your code like above solution. It should solve your problem.

Comment: Sure will try out with this one.